# How to search github repositories by lines of code, dependencies and versioning information?

Tags: github, data-mining

I would like to look for specific types of software projects. At this time I am seeking 10,000 - 30,000 lines of code projects that have rich and extensive I/O functionality.

In general I am interested in a method to find projects based on a combination of programming language, lines of code, and dependencies on other libraries.

Is there an efficient way to learn this information?

Answer (score -2):

There are plenty of tools available for searching large amounts of Github repositories. I've never used them, but you should be able to just Google and find those.

For less intense searching needs I use the Github advanced search feature.
You have the ability to discover repositories based on a relatively rich set of parameters.

Advanced Search: https://github.com/search/advanced